# Docker not running on windows 10 error: Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm trying to run docker on windows 10 Pro but I get this error: "Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS"

I have already enabled "Intel VT" and "XD bit" in BIOS settings As I read in this post "[Enable Hardware settings in BIOS to run Hyper V](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/iftekhar/2010/08/09/enable-hardware-settings-in-bios-to-run-hyper-v/)" but I don't have "Intel VT-d" and "Trusted Execution" in my BIOS settings to disable them.

These are my system specifications:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro build 14393.447
- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E7500
- Main: DG43GT

I have done the things said in this post "[Docker for Windows error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684974/docker-for-windows-error-hardware-assisted-virtualization-and-data-execution-p)" but nothing works!
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

After installed docker, on hp pavilion power 15-cb0xx

I got the same error:

[image: error]

Case 1: First I run these two commands with admin permission and restart the system but After the restart, I got the same error.

> dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
>
> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto

After checking the Windows feature as you see on the Image the second option 
(HyperV-Platform)  checked but looks different(**pale-> disabled by default**). 
You cannot enable or disable directly. You only able to update via PowerShell with first two commands I mentioned in Case 1.
After Case 1: it looks checked however the error was there.

[image: hiberv-disabled]

Case 2:

1. Turn off all the Hyper-V  feature
2. Open the bios setting re-enable the Hyper-V feature
3. Check the Hyper-V. **It should look like:**

   [image: hyper-v2]
4. Re-Install docker

Comment: This answer is the clearest among all in most posts related to DOCKER :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hyper-V on Windows 10 needs Second Level Address Translation (SLAT). This may not supported by this cpu. You can check this by using the sysinternals util coreinfo