# Do I need Windows 10 Pro to run Docker? Error: Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS

Tags: docker

I just installed Docker after upgrading my Windows 10 Home x64 to the version 2004 with the OS build 19041.264 (I needed to upgrade because Docker required me to have an OS buld >19018). Now if I want to launch docker I get this error `Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS`. I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684974/docker-for-windows-error-hardware-assisted-virtualization-and-data-execution-p) (it is old) question, but because they let me install docker on my windows 10 home I assume that I can somehow run it without hyper-v, cuz I can't download it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hyper-V role cannot be installed on Windows 10 Home. Hyper-V is used to run Linux kernel on Windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

The alternative solution is you can use Virtual box instead of Microsoft native Hyper-V. Docker toolbox comes with Virtual box. You can get details installation steps from below link.

https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

Comment: Thanks, your answer leads me somehow to enable the AMD-V which now let me run docker

Answer (score 1):

You will need Windows 10 Pro to run docker. Home edition is not useful for the purpose.