# Docker Desktop not running Windows 11 enterprise

Tags: docker

As soon as Start Docker Desktop 4.4.4 version , Docker service stopped with following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\vn54lf1\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: exit code: -1
 stdout: Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install


 stderr: 
   at Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) in C:\workspaces\PR-17132\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:line 146
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<DeployDistroAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17132\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 168
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<ProvisionAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17132\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 77
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17132\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 179
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17132\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17132\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17132\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
```

Comment: The error gives you a strong hint on how to fix the issue, have you tried the error message's suggestion?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, I tried multiple options. But unable to log into BIOS settings. So not sure what else can be done.

Answer (score 3):

The first line of the error tells you what to do:

```
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS
```

you need to reboot the machine and enter the BIOS settings to enable virtualization, this is a common requirement for virtualization platforms like Docker, Hyper-V, Android emulators etc...

see other answers to similar issue here: [Docker for Windows error: "Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684974/docker-for-windows-error-hardware-assisted-virtualization-and-data-execution-p)

Comment: I am using VMware windows virtual machine so unable to log into BIOS settings